ERROR Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'VectorIcons' could not be found
I get an error telling me that:

 ERROR  Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'VectorIcons' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary.Bridgeless mode: false. TurboModule interop: false. Modules loaded: {"NativeModules":["PlatformConstants","LogBox","Timing","AppState","SourceCode","BlobModule","WebSocketModule","DevSettings","DevToolsSettingsManager","Networking","Appearance","DevLoadingView","HeadlessJsTaskSupport","UIManager","DeviceInfo","ImageLoader","SoundManager","IntentAndroid","DeviceEventManager"],"TurboModules":[],"NotFound":["NativePerformanceCxx","NativePerformanceObserverCxx","RedBox","BugReporting","LinkingManager","VectorIcons"]}, js engine: hermes
 LOG  Running "ProjectName" with {"rootTag":11}
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: "ProjectName" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes

I get this error only after trying to use MaterialIcons inside my project imported via import MaterialIcons from '@react-native-vector-icons/material-icons';
If i remove MaterialIcons component an error disappear.
My Index.js look like this:
/**
 * @format
 */

import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);


I am using:
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.74.2

I have tried to clear gradle inside android by running cd android && gradlew clean , i have tried to clear cache, restarting Metro by running npm start , all methods doesn't seem to work.
I also added this lines of codes in android/app/build.gladle:

project.ext.vectoricons = [
    iconFontNames: [ 'MaterialIcons.ttf' ] // Adjust as necessary for other icon fonts
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle" 

but doesn't seem to work at all
